# R Shiny slider problems

Tags: r, shiny

Hi I'm trying to set up a Shiny app, but I'm having trouble accessing data from a slider that I've set up. For some reason, `input$slider1[1]` is not an integer, so I can't compare with with `Num_adults`, which *is* an integer.

This is the code where I try to access the slider

```
server<-function(input,output){  
  output$bar1 <- renderPlot({
    AllData1 <- AllData[!is.na(AllData$Num_adults),]
      AllData1$Num_adults <- as.numeric(AllData1$Num_adults)
      filter(AllData1$Num_adults >= input$slider1[1], AllData1$Num_adults <= input$slider1[2])
    ggplot(AllData1, aes(x=AllData1$Num_adults) + geom_histogram)
  })
}
```

and this is the code where I set up the slider. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
ui<-fluidPage(
  titlePanel(a(span("Data on Recipients of MSF.", style="color:purple"))),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("For the first graphic, you can..."),

      sliderInput(inputId = "slider1", 
                  label = h3("Number of adults in a household"), 
                  min = 0, max = 8, value = c(1,2))),

    mainPanel(plotOutput("bar1"))
  ))

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Adding `cat(class(input$slider1[1])); cat('\n');` to the server code before `ggplot` clearly shows that the class of this value is `integer` as printed on my console. I can't test the rest of your server code since I don't have access to `AllData1`.

Comment: There is also a problem in your line `ggplot(AllData1, aes(x=AllData1$Num_adults) + geom_histogram)`. It should be `ggplot(AllData1, aes(x= Num_adults)) + geom_histogram()`.

Comment: Also, your `filter` seems wrong, although not sure what package you are relying on for that method.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your server code to this should work (although I can't test without data):

```
library(dplyr)
server<-function(input,output){  
  output$bar1 <- renderPlot({
    AllData1 <- AllData[!is.na(AllData$Num_adults), ]
    AllData1 <- filter(AllData1, Num_adults >= input$slider1[1] &
                                   Num_adults <= input$slider1[2])
    ggplot(AllData1, aes(x = Num_adults)) + geom_histogram()
  })
}
```

You can simplify the `NA` filtering by incorporating into the `filter` call, but that is not essential.